# Airflow EmailOperator throws socket.error

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am facing below error while using EmailOperator intermittently. Any reason why I get it? Is there a way to avoid it?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Here is the code for EmailOperator

```
gate_3_email = EmailOperator(
    task_id="gate_3_email",
    to='sales@domain.com',
    subject=f'successfully completed! | {config["environment"]}',
    html_content=get_email_message("Gate 3"),
    retries=3,
    retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=30)
)
```

Adding a retry also intermittently fails, Do I need to explicitly increase timeout?

Note : I am using Kubernetes Executor, where each task instance is run in its own pod on a Kubernetes cluster. The worker pod then runs the task, reports the result, and terminates.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you have a problem with the email server connection.

To use the operator `EmailOperator`, you need to define the smtp configurations, you have two options:

- create a new Airflow connection of type `Email`, and provide it's name to the operator in the arg `conn_id`.
- configure the default SMTP connection which used by Airflow to send alerts, and used by default by this operator: (ex for gmail, you can use your own smtp server if you have one)

```
 [smtp]
    smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
    smtp_starttls = True
    smtp_ssl = False
    smtp_user = your gmail id
    smtp_password = your gmail password
    smtp_port = 25
    smtp_mail_from = from which email id you want send the mails(you can use your mail id)
```